# Is the Names of God question really "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, questions, closed-questions, vote-to-close

[What are the different names of God in the Bible and what do they mean?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/695/what-are-the-different-names-of-god-in-the-bible-and-what-do-they-mean)

At first glance this looks like a huge question, but *[take a look at the accepted (and most upvoted) answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/706/62)!* It provides the most important names with location and meaning and then details other names with their locations. I think this is a case of a great answer validating the question.

And the question itself has 42K views, making possibly the [most popular question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) here.

Am I the only one to think closing this question is <s>borderline criminal</s> a mistake?

Comment: A historical lock might be in order so it doesn't look inconsistent with high upvotes. It definitely needs something though; I doubt leaving it open will help the question any.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to close it to prevent people from adding new answers. The question is excellent and the answer is great as well. Any new answers would likely not add to the quality.

I would not be in favor of deleting it. What I hope would happen is that it remains closed, but is never deleted. It should be closed because it is a list question, which is generally not good. It should remain undeleted because the answer happens to be so good.

Comment: I was under the impression that closing (or, *on hold*) means that the question will be deleted in time. If that is not the case, your suggestion would be OK for me.

Comment: @Wikis I am under the impression that there are delete votes like close votes that high rep users have. I thought that rep threshold was 10K, but since you don't know what that is maybe it is 20K. So the question will only be deleted if community members vote to delete it.

Comment: [Low-rated questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) can be automatically deleted; not all closed questions are though.

Comment: @RyanFrame I think it is safe to say that this particular question will not be auto-deleted.